# How to handle app kill scenario in WorkManager?(workaround)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I'm using Work-manager for some background task, as per the documentation Work will be stopped when app is killed/force-stopped until the user reopens the app next time.

Is there any way I can restart the work even after the app is killed?

I'm using onetime work request

```
val uploadOneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker::class.java)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .addTag(TAG_UPLOAD_STATUS)
        .build()
```

Comment: Work is restarted automatically, until the constraints set are met. i.e. If the phone has low battery and on mobile data, it won't sync with server, unless the user is on WIFI and charging or have full battery.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, but my question is not that. I want to know is there any way if I can restart the workmanager even if the app is killed of course when the constraints are met.

Comment: You don't do anything manually. Workmanager internally works, and restarts itself, even when you app is killed by the user. (Which is, Swiped away from recent screen, or killed by CPU while app in background). I would advice watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4rYXsDs0 to understand more

Comment: Of course, I've watched this video, I've clearly mentioned it in my question. I think you haven't understood my question. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Force stop stops the application as a whole, all of your services, processes and everything permanently. When you force stop an app, it cannot even receive notifications, so, I'm pretty sure user needs to restart the app to get the job done.

By the way, getting an exception or swiping the app from recents is different, they allow work manager to process its jobs. My answer is only for explicit force stop.

Comment: In my case swiping the app from recent also stopping the work manager, it's not restarted until the app is re-opened. I'm trying in Oneplus 7. Is this is the only problem with some brands? I think I heard somewhere stock android won't do that when swiped from recent.

Comment: If your brand is something like Huawei or Xiaomi, yeah this is possible, I've come across some of them. They explicitly stop background tasks unless they are configured in some way. You can check the link https://dontkillmyapp.com/ to adjust your application / phone settings to let the worker work.